# Requesting clarifcaiton on file position in C

Tags: c

I am currently doing an exercise in KNKING C program a modern approach. This exercise.

(Question start)

Of the many techniques for compressing the contents of a file, one of the simplest and fastest is known as run-length encoding. This technique compresses a file by replacing sequences of identical bytes by a pair of bytes: a repetition count followed by a byte to be repeated. For example, suppose that the file to be compressed begins with the following sequence of bytes (shown in hexadecimal):

46 6F 6F 20 62 61 72 21 21 21 20 20 20 20 20

The compressed file will contain the following bytes:

01 46 02 6F 01 20 01 62 01 61 01 72 03 21 05 20

Run-length encoding works well if the original file contains many long sequences of identical bytes. In the worst case (a file with no repeated bytes), run-length encoding can actually double the length of the file.
(Question end)

I have a question regarding my code related to the exercise, this part of the code (and a particular line in question)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    FILE *fp,*fpout;
    char *outfile;
    unsigned char value,next,count;
    long int position;
    if (argc !=2)
    {
        printf("Error: Incorrect usage of program. Usage: c22p7.exe file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if ( (fp=fopen(argv[1], "rb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Unable to open file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    outfile = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 5);
    strcpy(outfile,argv[1]);
    strcat(outfile,".RLE");

    if ( (fpout=fopen(outfile,"wb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Unable to open file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    free(outfile);
    while ( fread(&value,sizeof(unsigned char),1,fp) > 0)
    {
        count = 1;
        position = ftell(fp);
        while ( fread(&next,sizeof(unsigned char),1,fp) > 0 && next == value)
        {
                count ++;
        }

        fwrite(&count,sizeof(unsigned char),1,fpout);
        fwrite(&value,sizeof(unsigned char),1,fpout);
        fseek(fp,-1L,SEEK_CUR);  /* THIS PARTICULAR LINE */
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fpout);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

with regards to `fseek(fp,-1L,SEEK_CUR);`, my rationale behind it was the program will keep reading the bytes until it has read the first byte that is different. It then moves back by one byte position hence the "-1L", so that on the next loop it will read back the byte. E.g.

01 01 01 01 02 02

It reads all the 01 until it reads the first 02, then `fseek()` moves the file position back by 1 byte so on the next iteration of the loop it will read the first 02 again. However, if I implement the code this way it doesn't work.

`fseek(fpin, position + (amount - 1), SEEK_SET);`

^ This works, however. The position is the position of the file after reading the first byte, and the amount is the number of bytes already read. I understand how this particular line of code works, but I do not understand why my `SEEK_CUR` method doesn't work. Thank you all for the help really

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: @EricPostpischil done sir, sorry my first ti,e using this site

Comment: Do you know about `ungetc()`?  It might save you a lot of trouble.  And all the `fread`/`fwrite`s of size 1 would be much simpler as `getc`/`putc` as well.

Comment: @NateEldredge sir what you suggest is i use getc/putc instead, and then once i encounter a new value i call ungetc once to put the new value back, and then continue with my loop? I see how that would work. My main question is, is my understanding of the statement "fseek(fp,-1L,SEEK_CUR); " wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do *not* need to back up the file. This will actually produce wrong results for the RLE.

If you *must*, there is an easier way. Use `ungetc(chr,fp);`

But, you can do this with a simpler loop. And, if you're going to get input char-at-a-time, use `fgetc` instead of `fread`.

You really only need a loop that does a *single* `fgetc` at the top of the loop.

You already have the basics: A variable that remembers the current character and another that remembers the previous one [which is the RLE char].

When the character change occurs, you just have to dump the accumulated RLE pair. And, *then* set the new character as the RLE char and a starting count of *one*. Setting the value to *one* is the crucial reason why you *don't* have to backtrack.

---

Here's a version that works [tested with the specified data]:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
rleout(int rlechr,int rlecnt)
{

    if (rlecnt > 0) {
        fputc(rlecnt,stdout);
        fputc(rlechr,stdout);
    }
}

int
main(void)
{
    int curchr;
    int rlechr = -1;
    int rlecnt = 0;

    while (1) {
        // get next character
        curchr = fgetc(stdin);

        // hit EOF
        if (curchr == EOF)
            break;

        // starting a new RLE
        if (curchr != rlechr) {
            // output the current RLE pair
            rleout(rlechr,rlecnt);

            // set new RLE pair
            rlechr = curchr;
            rlecnt = 1;
            continue;
        }

        // advance number of consecutive chars
        ++rlecnt;

        // if we're using the max space in a byte, we _have_ to dump the RLE
        // pair
        if (rlecnt >= 255) {
            rleout(rlechr,rlecnt);
            rlecnt = 0;
        }
    }

    // output final pair [if any]
    rleout(rlechr,rlecnt);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`fseek` works the way it's supposed to, but your code is buggy.

Think about what happens when you reach the end of the file.  For simplicity, think of a file that is only one byte long.  In the current version of the code, the inner `fread` will fail, but you don't have any special handling for that.  So the `fseek` will back up the file position by 1 byte, i.e. back to position 0, and the outer `fread` will reread the same character you just read, ad infinitum.  Your outer loop will never exit.

Basically, you're assuming that the last iteration of `fread` in the inner loop will always have advanced the file position by 1, which your `fseek` will effectively undo.  But that is not true when end-of-file is reached; in that case `fread` does not advance the file position.

With the other version of your code, you'll reach `fseek` with `position == 0` and `count == 1`, and seek to file position 1.  That's the end of the file, so the outer `fread` will terminate as desired.